# Fullpage.js - Setting value for 'setFitToSection' option based on if a div has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I have the code partially written but I am not sure what to put after the `if` and `else` parts. What I'm trying to do - whenever a section has class "four" and "active" I want to disable FitToSection option for fullpage.js. Fullpage.js has a built in setFitToSection Boolean which I'm using. This is what I have so far, what else do I need?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.four').hasClass('active') === true) {
        $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(false);
    } 
    else {
        $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check your `else` part you have typo and missed the `if`. Instead of that condition you can simply use this.
`if ($('.four').hasClass('active')) {                
            }
            else {
            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the callbacks fullpage.js provides, such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave`:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    autoScrolling:false,

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        var destination = $('.fp-section').eq(nextIndex - 1);

        if(destination.hasClass('four')){
           $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(false);
           console.log("setting fitToSection off");
        }else{
            $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(true);
            console.log("setting fitToSection on");
        }
    }
});
```

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1050/)

You don't need to check for the `active` class in this case because the destination section will always have it. Just check if it has the `four` class.

A shorter version of the same script can be:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    autoScrolling:false,

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        var destination = $('.fp-section').eq(nextIndex - 1);
        $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(!destination.hasClass('four'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah yes I should just check for that class, more simple. I plugged the shorter version in and it worked, thanks!

Comment: I spoke too soon @Alvaro. When I first enter the section with the class "four" it still moves to bottom of the section. After that it lets me scroll within that section without fitting to section.

Comment: Then you will need to set it off before accessing the section with the `four` class.

Comment: I'm shocked at myself but I actually managed to figure it out. I'll post it as an answer to my own question.

Comment: Again I spoke to soon. The scrolling works as I want but I borked something with the setting the variable and now my anchors will not work:
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
                var destination = $('.fp-section').val();
                if($destination.hasClass('fp-auto-height')) {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(false);
                } else {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(true);
                }
             }

Comment: Alternatively if I try the following it just disables FitToSection entirely: 
            onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
                
                if($('.fp-section').hasClass('fp-auto-height') && $('.fp-section').hasClass('active') ) {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(false);
                } else {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setFitToSection(true);
                }
            }